# What would be the regular expression to extract phone no from a text file

Tags: java, regex

I was trying using

```
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\s");
```

but it didn't work our for me .
 File contain text  would be

```
    New Requestmumbai  04/23/2016 you location **98XXXXXX38**

User  Admin Check  via mail.drop.com
```

Complete Code

```
public class ReadPhoneNo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          BufferedReader br = null;
          FileReader fileReader = null;
          List phList = null;
          try {
           fileReader = new FileReader(new File("F:\\email.txt"));

           br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
             Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\s");

           String line = null;
           phList = new ArrayList();
           System.out.println();
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

           Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            while (m.find()) {
             String ph = m.group(1).trim();
             if (!phList.contains(ph)) {
                 phList.add(ph);
             }
            }
           }
           for (int i = 0; i < phList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(phList.get(i));
           }
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.println("FileNotFoundException:- " + e.getMessage());
          } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.println("IOException:- " + e.getMessage());
          } finally {
           try {
            fileReader.close();
            br.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException Finally:- " + e.getMessage());
           }
          }

         }

}
```

Comment: Try `"\\b\\d{10}\\b"`.

Comment: are the `*` actually in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any `group` defined in your `regexpr`, try this `\\s(\\d{10})\\s`, you need to put between parentesis what you want to extract.

```
String value = "    New Requestmumbai  04/23/2016 you location 0123456789\n" +
    "\n" +
    "User  Admin Check  via mail.drop.com";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s(\\d{10})\\s");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
while (m.find()) {
    String ph = m.group(1);
    System.out.printf(ph);
}
```

**Output:**

```
0123456789
```

**NB:** No need to `trim()` the value anymore as you extract only the phone number nothing more.